# The vscode classpath cannot import my eclipse user_library correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

My vscode can't import eclipse user library correctly

I cannot import all of jars into the project, because it's too much. And I try to import the single jar like

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j.jar"/>
```

but it also cannot load correctly.

This is my .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src_syorg"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/ctp"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="seeyon/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

The 'JavaSE-1.8' library I can use it correctly, but the 'ctp' library cannot display correctly and cannot use it, too.

Project Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding external Jar files whithout maven or gradle `.classpath` file must be changed for the library.

1.create a folder named `lib` inside your project and add your `.jar` file into it

2.Configure paths in the `.classpath` like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xxxx.jar"/>
```

3.if it still thow error,Clean the workspace directory:`F1` - input `Clean` -`clean workspace`

[image] [image]

update:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54210217/10768653

Comment: I cleaned the workspace, so that this time I can import single jar. But I have more than 200 jar need to import, I need a method to import all of the jars.

Comment: @sorasyl you could refer to the update link,you might consider maven or gradle.