# What are the risks of using external libraries from unknown people ? Could it be malware?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I come across many problems that are easily solved by using a library created by someone who is not an authorized company. It works when implemented but I have fears that It might be a malware to hack my users. Can such thing happen ? Sorry I am a bit OCD :)

Edit:
How do I check whether a library is safe to use or not ?

Comment: That question does not belong here.. But yes. It needs to be verified source. And you mist understand the library in and out

Comment: How do I check if It's safe ? Is there some kind of tool that I can use ?

Comment: There isn't a magic pill to determine whats safe. Infact safe in itself is a subjective term. Whats not safe for you maybe a feature for me. All you must do before integrating 3rd party libraries is two things. First, check its popularity, like npm trends for node related libraries etc. Second, source code of each library is easily visible. Study it. Spend time on it. You won't regret later.

Comment: Okey, Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

If you use libraries from unknown people there is a risk that they have malware or other code that could be a virus.

When selecting libraries, it is important to use those that are "safe".

I don't think you should install libraries from unknown or unreliable sources.

@Edit

Please look at this links:

[How do I check installed JARs, external libraries, etc. on three different Java IDEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209062/how-do-i-check-installed-jars-external-libraries-etc-on-three-different-java)

https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/detecting-dependencies-known-vulnerabilities/

https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/

https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/13-tools-checking-security-risk-open-source-dependencies

Comment: How do I check it's safe to use ?